# Customization of Netbean PropertySheet API UI

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, propertysheet

Netbean PropertySheet API

I want to add two small image buttons for add/remove (image etc) action in PropertySet row of PropertySheet in Netbean.
In JTable we can have table render for this purpose.

Here in Netbean we can control paint for property row field, but no control over group row.

If any one can help.

Comment: Have a look at http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-property-editors.html#inplace-editor Unfortunately, This URL isn't reachable today due to planned maintenance so you can search for "Custom Inplace Editor" to find another resource.

Comment: Thanks, I know about custom Inplace editor like dropdown or drawing icon. Actually i need to add two small buttons near plus/minus icon in property set group. I don't found any example for that customization.

Comment: Ah, I see. This most probably isn't possible without editing the platform's source code. In other words, I know of no built in mechanism for editing a property set group's appearance in the way that you require.

Comment: Is there any way to select a table Cell/Property of Netbean property sheet by Code. Just like user click on it.